# Unexpected esc_html and esc_attr behaviour

Tags: search, escaping

On my site's search results page I am outputting the search term as follows:

```
<?php echo esc_html($_GET['s']); ?>
```

For the search term "SEARCH-TERM" (including the quotes) I would expect this to appear in the source as:

```
&quot;SEARCH-TERM&quot;
```

But what the source actually contains is:

```
\"SEARCH-TERM\"
```

which appears on the page as \"SEARCH-TERM\".

I am also outputting the search term as follows:

```
<input type="search" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_GET['s']); ?>">
```

This is appearing in the source as:

```
<input type="search" value="\"SEARCH-TERM\"">
```

and is actually appearing in the input box as \"SEARCH-TERM\" when viewed by the user.

The search term appears in the URL as %22SEARCH-TERM%22 which I believe is the correct URL representation of the search phrase.

I am struggling to understand why the characters are not being escaped as expected when using `esc_html` and `esc_attr`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I am running WordPress version 4.4.2.

Comment: $_GET and $_POST are "quoteescaped" by default. so you have to unescape first like this : `echo esc_html(wp_unslash($_GET["s"]))`

Comment: @mmm, why not a proper answer?

Comment: because an answer at another question was downvoted because the answer was too short. then from now a put the small answer in comments

Comment: @mmm Your previous answer was downvoted due to it only being a link. You should actually reread my message to that answer. Answers can be a one liner if it directly answers the question and does not send someone to another place where he/she might find an answer. Just a note, if your answer gets downvoted due to lack of info, you can always edit your answer, and if the edit is sufficient, the downvotes can be removed. I always remove my downvote if an answer was properly edited ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen my answer was not a just a link, I answer by giving the name of the function which provide the exact data which was researched and in these answers I try to add a link in order that next time, this personne will search on the codex before to ask here. finally my answer was so small that you only saw the link ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_search_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query) or [`the_search_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query) to return/output the search term as a properly escaped value, don't access `$_GET` directly. You're trying to escape something that's already URLencoded.